# Join on all fields without listing them?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Goal is to retrieve all exact records (each field is the same) from `table_a` that exist in `table_b`; however, there are many fields (lets say 100), which I don't want to type/list out.

Is there a way to compare tables based on records? Or have it auto-recognize and join-on  fields when not specified?

```
SELECT * FROM table_a 
WHERE EXISTS (
   select * from table_b
   -- where table_a.field1 = table_b.field1
   --   and ... 
   --   and table_a.field100 = table_b.field100
);
```

Comment: Select * means "show me everything". Can you re-write the question to just show the columns you actually want to show? It's kind of hard to answer right now when we can't see the list of columns that are in each table and which columns you want to join on.

Comment: @MeganSquire thank you for the consideration, but the point was to match records on all fields -- while I use UNIONs all the time, I totally forgot about INTERSECT and EXCEPT, as Bruno pointed out.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
select * from A
intersect
select * from B
```

see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-union.html

modified as suggested by user2989408